# react/react-router-dom/ не работают activeClassName

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Перестали работать activeClassName. Насколько я понял в v6 они теперь реализуются по другому

**Было**:

```
<NavLink activeClassName="active" to="/about" />
```

**Стало**:

```
<NavLink className={(navData) => navData.isActive ? "active" : "" } to="/about" />
```

Помогите решить проблему с модулями, я использую модули CSS
Импортирую как "s"[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

у меня есть класс для активной ссылки "link"
Как я могу поставить класс не "green", а как выражение например {s.link}

Comment: Ну так же как вы написали `{isActive ? s.link : "red"}`. И желательно эту функцию отдельно написать

Comment: s.link не работает, я так попробовать , и много способов, поэтому сюда написал

Comment: Не работает потому что вы задаете это к атрибуту `style`, а надо задать к атрибуту `className`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import styles from './styles.module.css';

const MyLink = () => (
  <NavLink
    to="/my-route"
    className={({ isActive }) =>
      isActive ? styles.active : undefined
    }
  >
    My route
  </NavLink>
);
```